# Set QTreeWidget indentation per row

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create a QTreeWidget that uses a specific indentation for non-root items. If I use `setIndentation(x)` it changes the indentation for all items, including the root. This means that if I set it to a low value, the expander icon will disappear.

```
|--| <- NOT this distance
 >  Root
        ItemA
        ItemB
    |--| <- this distance
```

I want it to look like this instead:

```
 >  Root
     ItemA
     ItemB
```

Is there any way to do it? My goal is to make it a bit like the property tree in Qt Designer where the property names are horizontally aligned-ish with their parents.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know either how to do that, but perhaps you can use an HTML code to insert a blank space in front of your items.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001034.htm